# Android: Squared button

Tags: android

How can I obtain a squared button in Android?

I tried to create a custom button extending the Button class as provided by this [link](http://android-layouts.com/category/tags/square).
I used the following code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SquareButton extends Button {

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        w = Math.min(w, h);
        h = w;

        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }
}
```

I obtain squared button, but they are too big as show [here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2eckzd3.jpg), in this case there is too much margin.
How can I draw squared button with an appropiate dimension like [this](http://oi57.tinypic.com/24gn0js.jpg), with an appropiate margin dimension?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have buttons in XML? If so then do it in that only instead of java. That's easier. Take a picture of the size you want and set it as the button's background and then set it's height and width to wrap_content

Comment: Have you tried applying width and height?

Comment: In my XML the button is like this: <com.example.customview.SquareButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

Comment: Use simple button, why do you want to you a custom button?

Comment: If no then try giving static value to this: `w = Math.min(120, 120);` something like that. Change the value according to your requirement.

Comment: I think your layout_weight is the reason they're so large. Remove that attribute and see if it looks any better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard Button and set its width and height in XML code. To easily change the size later on and have Buttons of different sizes you can put the values in the file res/values/dimens.xml like this:

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="square_button_normal">50dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="square_button_large">70dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and then use it like this in yout layout file:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/square_button_normal"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/square_button_normal"
    android:text="1"/>
```